# Replace the mapping text in ggplotly() plot without breaking the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a stacked bar chart below using ggplot and I convert it to interactive using `ggplotly()`. As you can see in the screenshot below the pop up text when I hover over a bar shows as "Name" the correct "Name" of the relative bar-in that case- DCH. I tried to replace that with a name of my choice but then the whole chart breaks down. So basically I would like to know if I can use "Name" in the background in order to display the chart but display another Name instead. The same for all of the 5 bars.

The code chunk which is related with this is:

```
    geom_col(mapping = aes(x = Name, y = count, fill = Class), width = rep(0.9,5),
             color = "black", position = position_fill(reverse = T)) +
    geom_text(size = 4, position = position_fill(reverse = T, vjust = 0.50), color = "black", 
              mapping = aes(x = Name, y = count, group = Class, label = round(count))) +
```

[image]

```
#DATA
Name<-c("DCH","DCH","DCH","DGI","DGI","DGI","LDP","LDP","LDP","RH","RH","RH","TC","TC","TC")
Class<-c("Class1","Class2","Overlap","Class1","Class2","Overlap","Class1","Class2","Overlap","Class1","Class2","Overlap","Class1","Class2","Overlap")
count<-c(2077,1642,460,1971,5708,566,2316,810,221,2124,3601,413,2160,1097,377)
FinalDF<-data.frame(Name, Class,count)




#PLOT


ggplotly(ggplot(data = FinalDF) +
    geom_col(mapping = aes(x = Name, y = count, fill = Class), width = rep(0.9,5),
             color = "black", position = position_fill(reverse = T)) +
    geom_text(size = 4, position = position_fill(reverse = T, vjust = 0.50), color = "black", 
              mapping = aes(x = Name, y = count, group = Class, label = round(count))) +
    annotate('text', size = 5, x = (5+1)/2, y = -0.1, label = c('A'), angle = 90) +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('lemonchiffon', 'palegreen3', 'deepskyblue2'),breaks=c("Class1", "Overlap", "Class2"), labels = c(paste("Unique to","DB"), "Overlap", "Unique to Comparison Dataset "),
                      guide = guide_legend(label.position = 'left', label.hjust = 0, label.vjust = 0.5)) )
```

Comment: You over-complicated the problem so much. your plot can be achieved much simpler than what you have in your function. That's why we have hoovering feature for almost anything on that plot. Start from scratch. re-write your function and avoid from adding unnecessary aesthetics and mappings and scales. Then if you could reproduce the problem, show us something legible. Cheers.

Comment: I did as told. I tried not to delete everything because it may help someone understand the logic of this plot

Comment: +1. Hope someone gets here with an answer (I am too tired to try, sorry mate). But just so you know. If you save the plotly object, you will see that `ggplyobject$x$data[[#]]$hoverinfo` shows the hover info. Read about that a bit and how it can be manipulated. p.s. `#` means a number referring different components of the graph.

Comment: Thanks for the info I ll take a look. If u find an answer feel free to share. Tooltip might help based on this https://blog.cpsievert.me/2018/01/30/learning-improving-ggplotly-geom-sf/ ?

Answer (score 0):

The `tooltip` argument might be in the right direction.

```
  library(sf)
  library(plotly)
  # Create the stacked bar plot using ggplot()
  stackedBarPlot<- ggplot(data = FinalDF) +
    geom_col(mapping = aes(x = Name, y = count, fill = Class), width = rep(0.9,5),
             color = "black", position = position_fill(reverse = T)) +
    geom_text(size = 4, position = position_fill(reverse = T, vjust = 0.50), color = "black", 
              mapping = aes(x = Name, y = count, group = Class, label = round(count))) +
    annotate('text', size = 5, x = (5+1)/2, y = -0.1, label = c('A'), angle = 90) +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('lemonchiffon', 'palegreen3', 'deepskyblue2'),breaks=c("Class1", "Overlap", "Class2"), labels = c(paste("Unique to","DB"), "Overlap", "Unique to Comparison Dataset "),
                      guide = guide_legend(label.position = 'left', label.hjust = 0, label.vjust = 0.5))+
    geom_sf(aes(fill=Class,text=paste(Name,"DB")))

  stackedBarPlot%>%
    ggplotly(tooltip = "text")
```